# Message: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pkey"

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

I am facing a problem with postgresql where it automatically takes the primary key from another table & then it starts from there.I have searched too much & landed to a solution by @burt beckwith
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/One-hibernate-sequence-is-used-for-all-Postgres-tables-td1351722.html 
But it doesn't solve my problem I am still facing the issue with the insertion.Grails is inserting the value on existing primary key which through the exception of

> Message: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tableName_pkey"

please make me correct.

Comment: could you please provide DDL for *one table* and *another one*  by running `\d+` _table_ and _anotherOne_ ?

Comment: @Dmitry will you please elaborate , there is existing table & then using gorm I am trying to insert the value

Comment: To get the ddl, connect to the database using psql, then run `\d+ TABLE_NAME_HERE` Do that for both tables. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html